# TWebBrowser with IE8 and IE10

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, twebbrowser

I'm using Dephi to automate mass user account. With WindowsXP3 and
 IE8 I can use mass user account.

Example: I have 2 `TWebBrowser`, the `WebBrowser1` uses `user1,pass1`
account. the `WebBrwoser2` uses `user2,pass2` account. Using IE8 I can do
this.

But with IE10 I can't. Is there some settings to change in
IE10 to make this perform like IE8?

What is the setting to be change in IE10?

Yes, I created 2 different threads.

```
type
  twebthread1 = class(tthread)
  private
  flags:OleVariant;
  tweb1:TWebBrowser;
  constructor create;
  procedure execute; override;
end;

type
  twebthread2 = class(tthread)
  private
  flags:OleVariant;
  tweb2:TWebBrowser;
  constructor create;
  procedure execute; override;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe you can try from two different threads? Or maybe you can use Chrome instead of Ie?

Comment: I tried using 2 threads with IE10, but it's the same, it does stay on same session, but in IE8 it does.  I don't want to use Chrome.

Comment: i meant you should CREATE TWebBrowser objects in two different threads, not use them in different threads after they wer created by VCLMainThread from DFM. Did you tried that way ?

Comment: @Arioch, I'm afraid it won't be enough (maybe, but that's my guess, on process level). What's worse, you need to isolate cache and cookies for each instance and embedded browsers tend to use the IE storage. And to be honest, I don't believe that it was ever possible to achieve this separation.

Comment: @TLama don't forget that both HtmlHelp and MSIMN/MSOE/Windows Mail/Live Mail use Internet Explorer as their back-end (including loading pictures into HTML messages by HTTP protocol). So the isolation is built into IE core, but its use might require an insane lot of boilerplate code... I wonder it TEmbeddedWB has any advances in this sense

Comment: @Arioch, I was talking about pure `TWebBrowser` (`WebBrowser` ActiveX control wrapper). I doubt you can force it to not use the shared IE stuff (at least without implementing any extending interface), but maybe I'm wrong. Still I'm a bit confused, how the sites the OP was able to log on with different accounts from two instances of `TWebBrowser` in the same process work (assuming they're using the same cache storage).

Comment: @TLama site authorisation state might be kept in cookies/WebStorage or might be passed as a hash in a hidden form field or URL get-parameter. In latter case there is nothing to be shared in any kind of storage. Though that all is mere speculation and would be fruitless.

Comment: Yes, I created two different threads.

Comment: Please stop block-quoting your post. Block-quotes are for marking **things you're quoting**, not **your own** text, and certainly not your own **code**. If you need help formatting your posts, click the orange **?** above the top right corner of the text area into which you're typing you post.

Comment: "Yes, I created two different threads." i was not talking about creating threads, but about creating web-browsers inside running objects

Comment: How will I do that? Can you post a simple sample code, please.